# How to set a timeout to tileerror on L.tileLayer?

Tags: javascript, jquery, leaflet, mapbox

I am getting layers from a WMS service, but sometimes it happens that the connection to the server times out. In those cases, the application hangs for a long time waiting for a NET_ERR, but the timeout is too long.

I am catching the error with "tileerror":

```
myLayer.on('tileerror', function(error, tile) {
    console.log(error);
    console.log(tile);
    switchToBackupServer();
    });
```

How can I shorten the default timeout and take the corrective action?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How can I shorten the default timeout and take the corrective action?

You can't. It's browser-specific, and it doesn't have an API.

You can, however, create your own subclass of `L.TileLayer` and add some extra logic. See these lines in the default implementation of `L.TileLayer.prototype.createTile`:

```
    DomEvent.on(tile, 'load', Util.bind(this._tileOnLoad, this, done, tile));
    DomEvent.on(tile, 'error', Util.bind(this._tileOnError, this, done, tile));
```

You could trigger a shorter timeout with something like:

```
    var loadCallback = Util.bind(this._tileOnLoad, this, done, tile);
    var errorCallback = Util.bind(this._tileOnError, this, done, tile);

    DomEvent.on(tile, 'load', loadCallback);
    DomEvent.on(tile, 'error', errorCallback);

    setTimeout(function(){
        // Do nothing if the tile has already been loaded successfully
        if (tile.loaded) return;

        // Prevent any further events from triggering
        DomEvent.off(tile, 'load', loadCallback);
        DomEvent.off(tile, 'error', errorCallback);

        // Trigger the error
        errorCallback();
    });
```

There are probably some race conditions that I cannot foresee right now, but that's the general idea.

Comment: For readers: in case you do not import Leaflet classes individually but the entire UMD bundle, you should use `L.DomEvent`, `L.Util` etc. instead of `DomEvent`, `Util`